# How to retrieve data from hashtable when value is given as an object

Tags: c#

hi I want to enter three values into hash table so I entered one value as key and other two converted them into object and passed as value`

```
class UsingHashTable
{
    public int empId;
    public String empName { get; private set; }
    public decimal salary { get; private set; }

    public UsingHashTable(string empName, decimal salary)
    {
        this.empName = empName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    Hashtable employeeHash = new Hashtable();

    UsingHashTable emp;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee ID ");
    empId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee Name ");
    empName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Salary of the employee ");
    salary = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    emp = new  UsingHashTable(empName,salary);

    employeeHash.Add(empId, emp);
}
```

Now the actual problem comes! How to retrieve the values from the hashtable where key is coming but from value I need to retrieve two values how??

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry temp in employeeHash) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(temp.Key + " " + temp.Value.eName + " " + temp.Value.salary);
}
```

I am exactly getting the error at temp.Value.eName and temp.Value.salary

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast `temp.Value` to your type

```
Console.WriteLine(temp.Key + " " + ((UsingHashTable)temp.Value).eName + " " + ((UsingHashTable)temp.Value).salary);
```

But I would definitely recommend using `Dictionnary<TKey,TValue>` which will avoid the need to cast.

```
var employeeHash = new Dictionary<int,UsingHashTable>
var emp = new  UsingHashTable(empName,salary);
employeeHash.Add(empId, emp);
```

And your loop will work just fine

```
 foreach(var temp in employeeHash) 
 {
     Console.WriteLine(temp.Key + " " + temp.Value.eName + " " + temp.Value.salary);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable.Key and Hashtable.Key are of object types. You need to cast these to your desired objects (UsingHashTable in your case) and then retrieve its properties (empName, empId)

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry temp in employeeHash)
{
    int id = (int) temp.Key;
    UsingHashTable employee = (UsingHashTable) temp.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(id + " " + employee.eName + " " + employee.salary);
}
```

Its better to use Dictionarty() here,

Answer (score 0):

It is because late binding not supported in C# by default.  it means C# Identifies the `temp.Value` as `Object` not `UsingHashTable`. and `object` class does not have `Name` property.
to resolve this simply cast `temp.Value` to `UsingHashTable`.
example:
        var temp2=(UsingHashTable)temp.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(temp2.Name);